# Highstock - how to filter only one dataset

Tags: highcharts

My example here: http://jsfiddle.net/eb67eddt/

I have some "Plan" (data name - plan) with 5M in the end of march, 10M in the end of Jun and so on.

```
"data": [
            [1420059600000, 0],
            [1427749200000, 5000000],
            [1435611600000, 10000000],
            [1443560400000, 15000000],
            [1451509200000, 25000000]
        ],
```

All data is presenting in example. I need to make Highstock to show "Current" data with "Current" dates.

```
"data": [
            [1421096400000, 62267],
            ...
            [1424725200000, 1328255]
        ]
```

My "Plan" data is like helper and i don't need to filter by "Plan". Only by "Current". So on Highstock init I need to see chart with time range from 12/Jan to 23/Feb. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can't you remove unnecessary points from your array? I'm not sure where exactly is the problem. Could you make some jsFiddle with issue for better understanding?

Comment: So I need something like here http://jsfiddle.net/wLc3jfru/ but with all "Plan" data

Comment: Why do you need all "Plan" data if you don't want to display that data? Remove points with x-value higher than last x-value in "Current" data and will be working properly, I think.